# umount: it seems [device] is mounted multiple times

Tags: mount, umount

i was finishing up a job with a compact flash when, trying to unmount it:

```
#> umount /dev/sda2 
umount: it seems /dev/sda2 is mounted multiple times
```

Looking at what `mount` says:

```
#> mount | column -t | grep sda2
/dev/sda2  on  /mnt/flashrw  type  ext3      (rw,nosuid,nodev)
/dev/sda2  on  /mnt/flashrw  type  ext3      (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=myuser)
```

it seems that I accidentally mounted the same device on the same location (though in two different ways).

I tried to unmount it many times also with:

```
#> umount /mnt/flashrw 
umount: it seems /mnt/flashrw is mounted multiple times
```

with no luck. Finally, I tried:

```
#> sudo umount -f /dev/sda2
```

but `umount` locked completely.

So the question is: **and now?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably it was a kernel bug due to an unstable patch interaction. I was using a 3.4.11 vanilla kernel patched with the corresponding [RT-PREEMPT patch](http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/rt/3.4/older/) [by Ingo Molnar](https://rt.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/RT_PREEMPT_HOWTO).

Due to a [severe memory leak](http://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-rt-users/msg08666.html), I moved to 3.6.4 vanilla + RT-PREEMPT patch and now the system seems to be really stable. The problem has never presented again. Hope this may help someone in the future.

Comment: Why is this marked as the answer?

Comment: Because it was what really was happening to me. It was not the beginner use case "I can't umount my usb pen and I don't even know about the existence of lsof or fuser", it was a kernel issue due to an unofficial (and problematic) kernel patch applied to a custom kernel.

Answer (score 24):

Try running this command:

```
sudo umount /mnt/flashrw
```

Comment: Yup, fixed it for me. That was the most misleading error message I have seen in a a while.

Comment: what if you do not have sudo access on the server